# Norm-preserving rectangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f$ be a linear transformation $f:\Bbb 
R^n\rightarrow \Bbb R^m$, where $n>m$, such that

$$
\textbf{y} = f(\textbf{x})=\textbf{W}\textbf{x}
$$

Since $n>m$, $f$ forms a data compression layer. If a solution for $\textbf{W}$ is 2-norm preserving, what can be said about the solution matrix $\textbf{W}$?

My attempt:

I have looked into orthogonality ($\textbf{W}^T\textbf{W}$ be $\textbf{I}$) and if maximum singular value of $\textbf{W}$ is unit, but neither was true.

Comment: What do you mean by a ‘compressive’ linear transformation? And since $n>m$, it is impossible that $\|f(x)\|_2=\|x\|_2$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^n$. Then what do you mean by ’$2$-norm preserving‘?

Comment: If $\|Wx\|_2 = \|x\|_2$ for all $x$, then $W$ is called an "isometry".  But that implies $n \le m$.